# DBUNIT flatXmlDataSet file and columns with special characters

Tags: java, testing, junit, integration-testing, dbunit

I'm using dbunit for integration test purpose. 
I have a table in which there is a column with name : **s#name**.

The problem is that, I'm using FlatXmlDatasetFile format to inject data to the database so, I'm facing a xml validation problem related to this column name.

The question is, in general, How can I deal with special characters when they are used in column names?

Answer (score 1):

Since attribute names in an XML document cannot contain the '#' character (see http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html and http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn), this column name is a challenge.

When you want to read data from an XML file into a database (using the `FlatXmlDataSetBuilder` class), you are limited to what XML supports. See [flatXmlTableTest.xml](https://github.com/johnbhurst/dbunit/blob/master/dbunit/src/xml/flatXmlTableTest.xml) for an example: "COLUMN0" is a column name used for table "TEST_TABLE".

Perhaps there are other formats that DbUnit supports or else you could perhaps read the data yourself and implement the `IDataSet` interface with a custom class.

Comment: I've used after all, the XmlDataSetFile. It worked with all the inconvenients of this format.
I've found, for my problem, an open issue reported the dbunit team, but they seam absent. Thanks for the answer.